# I need to scrape numbers from a site but they don't have tags

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
import re
driver = webdriver.Edge(service= Service("C:/Users/Peterven/Documents/msedgedriver.exe"))
#driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:/Users/Peterven/Documents/msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://nigeria.startuphrtoolkit.com/top-startups-in-nigeria")
results = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
#print((soup.find("p", class_=False, id=False).find_next_sibling(text=True)))
driver.quit()
for element in soup.find_all(attrs= "wpb_wrapper"):
    name = element.findAll("strong")
    if name not in results:
        results.append(name)
        
#print(soup.find('strong':contains("Contact"))
```

scraping the strong tags also returns the first one from the parent class even though I use findAll

Comment: get the html then use regular expressions to scrape the data.

Comment: What data are you trying to get, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The contact is static so you don't need overhead of browser.

The easiest approach is to find a pattern e.g. css selector list, which divides the listings into sections you can loop over and extract the desired contact numbers from.

There are a number of css selector lists you could use. A fairly stable one, IMO, would be

```
.vc_column-inner:has(h3:not(:-soup-contains("Conclusion")))
```

The `:not` is to exclude the final Conclusion block.

Once you have your blocks/listings to loop over then you can integrate your current attempt to use `:contains` or `:-soup-contains` to extract the numbers

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://nigeria.startuphrtoolkit.com/top-startups-in-nigeria', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
sections = soup.select('.vc_column-inner:has(h3:not(:-soup-contains("Conclusion")))')

for section in sections:
    
    print(section.select_one('h3').text)
    
    contact = section.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Contact")')
    
    if contact is None:
        print('No contact number')
    else:
        print(contact.next_sibling.replace(':', '').strip())
    print()
```